# Web Application Failed to Connect to Server Due to CORS Policy Block

Tags: html, mysql, reactjs, cors

I've spent some time trying to resolve this issue, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. My application is all set up and should work just fine, but I keep recieving the same error no matter what I do to fix it:

`Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/login' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/register') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

When going to **http://localhost:8080/login**, where Spring Security's default login page is still able to run, everything works perfectly, but when using my front-end application, I receive the above error.

Back-End -- JWTAuthenticationFilter:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");


        if(authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if(userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()

                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }

    }
```

Back-End -- SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/api/v1/auth/authenticate", true);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Front-End -- Login:

```
import React from 'react'
import {useRef, useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
import { AuthContext} from '../auth/authProvider.js'

import { axios }from '../auth/axios.js'


const LogIn = () => {

    //If authenticate, set Auth state and store
    const {setAuth} = useContext(AuthContext);

    //References:
    const userRef = useRef(); //set focus when load
    const errRef = useRef(); //set focus when error

    const [email, setUser] = useState(''); //set state of user input for form
    const[password, setPwd] = useState(''); //set state of password input for form
    const[errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState(''); //set state of error we might recieve
    const[success, setSuccess] = useState(false); //success return... will be USED TO NAVIGATE

    useEffect(()=> {
        userRef.current.focus(); //put focus on userRef when loads
    }, [])

    useEffect(()=> {
        setErrMsg(''); //if user changes after error, hide errors
    }, [email, password]);
    
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevents form from reloading page

        const credentials={email, password}

        const settings = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                method:"POST",
                mode: "cors",
                Accept: 'application/json',
                headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"},
                headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"},
                headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Request-Header-Field-Mode"},
                withCredentials: true,
                body:JSON.stringify(credentials)
                    
                }
        };

        try {

            console.log(credentials) //log to console

            
            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/register', settings);
            const data = await res.json();
            return data;
            
            //setUser('');
            //setPwd('');
            //setSuccess(true); //sets every login to be successful
        } catch (err) {
            if(!err?.response){ //IF recieves no response
                setErrMsg('No Server Response.');
            } else if (err.response?.status === 400){
                setErrMsg('Missing Username or Password');
            } else if (err.response?.status === 400){
                setErrMsg('Unauthorized');
            } else {
                setErrMsg('Login Failed');
            }

            errRef.current.focus();
        }
        //console.log(email, password);     //Used for Testing Purposes
        
    }

    return (

        <>

        {success ? (

            <section>
                <h1>You are logged in</h1>
            </section>

        ) : (

        //Bootstrap login form:
        <div>

        <section>
            <p ref={errRef} className={errMsg ? "errmsg" : "offscreen"} aria-live="assertive">{errMsg}</p> {/*display error message*/}
        </section>
            <div className="container">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="username" className="form-label">Email address</label>
                    <input 
                        type="email" 
                        className="form-control" 
                        id="username" 
                        aria-describedby="emailHelp" 
                        ref={userRef}
                        autoComplete="off"
                        onChange={(e)=> setUser(e.target.value)}
                        value={email}
                        required/>
                    <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input 
                        type="password" 
                        className="form-control" 
                        id="password" 
                        onChange={(e)=> setPwd(e.target.value)}
                        value={password}
                        required/>
                    
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
            </form>

            <p>
                <br />
                <span className="line">
                    {/* put link to register page below */}
                    <a href="#">Create an Account</a>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        
        )} </>
    )
}

export default LogIn
```

Let me know if you need anything else, but I really appreciate the help. I've spent way to long trying to resolve this error. Thanks again!

Comment: It's backend problem, tell your backend developer to add `cors` into your api.

Comment: Was that not done above? when I set my response headers in JWTAuthenticationFilter?

Comment: I don't know which language you are using but the problem is in backend, you need to set an origin to bypass the cors problem, usually for development it is `*`

Comment: @NishargShah, I believe I did do that in my code above. Am I changing the headers in the wrong class, or am I just doing it wrong?